# Node js beginner getting an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my code for a simple node.js application:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;

http.createServer(function onRequest(req, res) {

var urlParts = url.parse(req.url);

var doc = '/docs' + urlParts.pathname;

path.exists(doc, function fileExists(exists) {

    if (exists) {

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        fs.createReadStream(doc).pipe(res);

    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end('Not Fouind\n');
    }
});
}).listen(port);
```

When I try to run it I get an error that reads:

```
path.exists(doc, function fileExists(exists) {
                                    ^
                                  TypeError:Undefined is not a function
```

This is copied off of a tutorial so I'm not sure what's going on. (PS: I'm using Visual Studio)

Comment: @DavidSherret — But named function expressions are easier to debug when you get a stacktrace.

Answer (score 11):

I think `path.exists` is deprecated. I've been using `fs.exists`. Try that.

Comment: @dismal1290 as a courteous gesture to the answerer, can you please mark it as accepted answer if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
fs.exists(doc, function fileExists(exists) {

    if (exists) {

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        fs.createReadStream(doc).pipe(res);

    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end('Not Fouind\n');
    }
});
```

`path.exists` is not a function, the function exists in the `fs` module under [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback).